# My subreport is not detected in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, rdlc, visual-studio-2022

I am currently attempting to create a report using rdlc in Visual Studio 2022. I ran into a problem where every time I run the program

`The subreport 'foo' could not be found at the specified location bar. Please verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct`

Everywhere I've looked no one mention anything about publishing the subreport beforehand, they all just enter the subreport name in the subreport properties panel

Update:
I found this warning after running a few test, not sure if this is helpful

```
Warning: An error occurred while executing the subreport 'RunDetailsSubReport' (Instance: 0): The report definition for report 'RunDetails' has not been specified (rsErrorExecutingSubreport)
```

Comment: Are you typing in the sub report name or picking it from the drop-down list? If it's not in the drop-down, then VS isn't recognizing it in the solution.

Comment: I'm typing it in. I guess VS is not recognizing it, how can I add it? @HannoverFist

Comment: The subreport would need to be in the same solution in VS as the main report. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on Reports and Add > Existing Item and select the missing subreport.

Comment: It looks like they're both in the same solution already.

Comment: Hmm - something's wrong if it isn't showing up in the `Use this report as subreport` drop down which is leading to your Not Found error. I haven't had this issue or know what else to check. Maybe check the solution folder and make sure the sub report file is there.